# grep a file with processid

Tags: grep, process

I am creating ftp.log.processid at run time via my script

now i need to grep this file for a word 'get'

`grep -i "get" $ftp_log.$!`

I am using the above expression - but it always shows no such file or directory 
and i see a dot (.) created at the end at run time 
as below 
grep -i ftp.log.1234.
why is there a dot at the end of grep - and how to avoid getting this created at run time and grep correctly

Comment: And why is the underscore being changed to a dot?

Comment: The only reason I can think for the trailing dot is that `$ftp_log` has some nasties in it (for example, try `ftp_log=$'...............\rftp.log'` and then `echo "$ftp_log.$!"`). Best advice in these situations is to run your script with `set -x` to see exactly what's happening line-by-line.

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
grep -i "get" $ftp_log.$!
```

uses a variable called `ftp_log`.  If you have no such variable, the value substituted will be empty.

You might have meant

```
grep -i "get" "ftp_log.$!"
```

assuming `$!` is the process ID of the most recently started background process.

Comment: Since OP is seeing `grep -i ftp.log.1234.`, the variable seems to be substituted fine, except for the `.` at the end which they're complaining about.

Comment: yes  your understanding is correct- I am trying to grep this inside shell script as below

Comment: 'gre p -i "get" "ftp_log.$!"` but on running the script it's showing as grep -i "get" ftp.log.1234. where 1234 is the process id

Comment: @Dev It is unclear what the issue is and what is wrong.

Comment: @Dev You have to tell us _exactly_ what you are doing. You have used `ftp_log` and `ftp.log` interchangeably, and you have not told us what it is that displays `grep -i "get" ftp.log.1234.` when you say "_it_ shows". One possible issue is that the script file was written on a Windows machine in which case it has carriage returns before each newline. Use `dos2unix` on the file to convert it to a Unix text file.